# Test Database Connectivity

Tags: powershell

Is there an easy way to test the connectivity to a MS SQL Server instance from a client (without loading any SQL assemblies) with PowerShell?

**MS Sql:** Servername\Instance Port 1433

How can I test the connectivity to the server with PowerShell from a normal client?

Answer (score 60):

Use the [`SqlConnection` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) to test a connection. You *don't have to load any SQL assemblies*.

**Helper function:**

```
function Test-SQLConnection
{    
    [OutputType([bool])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    Position=0)]
        $ConnectionString
    )
    try
    {
        $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString;
        $sqlConnection.Open();
        $sqlConnection.Close();

        return $true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return $false;
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
Test-SQLConnection "Data Source=localhost;database=myDB;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;"
```

Comment: Return `$_.Exception.Message` in the catch scope to get the error message.

Comment: @PawBaltzersen Good point but the cmdlet does explicit return a boolean because it is intended to return true or false whether the test was successfull or not. Most users probably don't care about the actual failure for the test.

Comment: I know, just thought I'd mention it :)

Answer (score 17):

This is basically the same as Martin's answer, only the connection string is build from the parameters, and the time taken to connect is measured.

e.g:

```
Test-SQLDatabase -Server SQLServer -Database SomeDB -Username SQLUser -Password password
```

or

```
Test-SQLDatabase -Server Server1\SQLExpress -Database SomeDB -UseWindowsAuthentication
```

.

```
function Test-SQLDatabase 
{
    param( 
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)] [string] $Server,
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$True)] [string] $Database,
    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName="SQLAuth")] [string] $Username,
    [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName="SQLAuth")] [string] $Password,
    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName="WindowsAuth")] [switch] $UseWindowsAuthentication
    )

    # connect to the database, then immediatly close the connection. If an exception occurrs it indicates the conneciton was not successful. 
    process { 
        $dbConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        if (!$UseWindowsAuthentication) {
            $dbConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server; uid=$Username; pwd=$Password; Database=$Database;Integrated Security=False"
            $authentication = "SQL ($Username)"
        }
        else {
            $dbConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server; Database=$Database;Integrated Security=True;"
            $authentication = "Windows ($env:USERNAME)"
        }
        try {
            $connectionTime = measure-command {$dbConnection.Open()}
            $Result = @{
                Connection = "Successful"
                ElapsedTime = $connectionTime.TotalSeconds
                Server = $Server
                Database = $Database
                User = $authentication}
        }
        # exceptions will be raised if the database connection failed.
        catch {
                $Result = @{
                Connection = "Failed"
                ElapsedTime = $connectionTime.TotalSeconds
                Server = $Server
                Database = $Database
                User = $authentication}
        }
        Finally{
            # close the database connection
            $dbConnection.Close()
            #return the results as an object
            $outputObject = New-Object -Property $Result -TypeName psobject
            write-output $outputObject 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

That depends on what you actually want to test. If you just want to verify that you can connect to the port on the remote host something like this will do:

```psh
$server = 'servername'
$port   = 1433

$tcp = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
if ([void]$tcp.Connect($server, $port)) {
  'connected'
} else {
  'not connected'
}
$tcp.Dispose()
```

If you want to verify that a connection to an SQL Server instance can be established you'll need something like this:

```psh
$dbhost = 'servername'
$dbinst = 'instance'
$dbname = 'master'

$username = ...
$password = ...

$cs = "Server=$dbhost\$dbinst;Database=$dbname;User Id=$username;" +
      "Password=$password;"

$cn = New-Object -COM 'ADODB.Connection'
$cn.ConnectionString = $cs
try {
  $cn.Open()
  if ($cn.State -eq 1) {
    'connected'
    $cn.Close()
  } else {
    'not connected'
  }
} catch {
  'not connected'
}
```

Comment: On Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 R2 you can also use the Test-NetConnection cmdlet like so: Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'servername' -Port 1433

Comment: I tried the script and got an error "Data source name not found and no default driver specified". This was resolved when I added `DRIVER={SQL Server}` in the connection string.

Comment: To print the exception, use `echo $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message` in the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the ConnectionState enum to check the database connection state.

[Documentation on this enum can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.connectionstate?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

It can be accessed with the following: `[System.Data.ConnectionState]::Open`

Other options are `Broken`, `Closed`, `Connecting`, `Executing`, and `Fetching`.

###### Example:

```
class Database
{
    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]$Connection

    [void]Connect
    {
        $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
        $sqlConnection.Open()

        $this.Connection = $sqlConnection
    }
    
    [bool]IsConnected
    {
        return $this.Connection.State -eq [System.Data.ConnectionState]::Open
    }
}
```